# How to set cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALISED on WSL2 using Torch

Tags: python, pytorch, wsl-2

I am trying to test deep neural networks with `Torch==2.0.0cu+117`.

- I use WSL2 Ubuntu on Windows 10
- I have NVIDIA T1200 Laptop GPU and I have installed a compatible version of driver on Windows
- I have installed WSL as administrator using `wsl --install` and `wsl --update` and some required libraries
- On WSL2, When I tap `nvidia-smi`, I get this
  driver NVIDIA Info[image]
- I have installed Cudatoolkit version 12.1 with local repo (.deb) and have used `export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-12.1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}` and
  `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-12.1/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}`
- I have also installed CuDNN version 8.9.1.23
- And then I Install Anaconda (`Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64`) and create an conda environment with `conda create -n my_env python=3.8 cython`. I have install torch version 2.0.0cu+117 and other python required libraries.

When I compile my script on my environment, I get this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):`
  File "test.py", line 169, in <module>
    tester.infer()
  File "test.py", line 103, in infer
    pred = self.model(pts.cuda(), None)
  File "/home/amadou/anaconda3/envs/cyconvlite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/9822223E/Stage3A/WSL_ressources/model_init/models/networks.py", line 47, in forward
    _, y0 = self.cv_in(x_in, x_in, y_in, 16)
  File "/home/amadou/anaconda3/envs/cyconvlite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/9822223E/Stage3A/WSL_ressources/model_init/models/kernels.py", line 253, in forward
    y_out = self.conv(y_out.transpose(2,1)).view(batch_size, n_pts_out, self.out_features)
  File "/home/amadou/anaconda3/envs/cyconvlite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amadou/anaconda3/envs/cyconvlite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 313, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/home/amadou/anaconda3/envs/cyconvlite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 309, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv1d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
```

I have tried to reinstall WSL, CuDNN and recreated the conda environment, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Is your question really `How to set cuDNN error: CU…`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing a new NVIDIA driver, the Cudatoolkit and cuDNN on Windows.